# Counting occurrences of integers in a two-dimensional array in C# visual studio

Tags: c#, arrays, visual-studio, counting

I have code that loops through a two dimensional array and counts the occurrences of each integer, 1-9, and outputs them in their respective labels.

I wrote this myself and kind of struggled to do it.

Can someone explain to me why this works the way it does? Specifically this line:

> count[numbers[row, col]]++;

```
int[ , ] numbers =  { { 1, 8 }, 
                                  { 4, 5 }, 
                                  { 7, 9 }, 
                                  { 3, 1 }, 
                                  { 9, 3 }, 
                                  { 5, 9 }, 
                                  { 8, 8 }, 
                                  { 9, 9 }, 
                                  { 7, 3 }, 
                                  { 2, 1 }, 
                                  { 5, 4 } };

            int[] count = new int [10]; // use this for counting occurrences



            // nested loop --- need to loop through the rows, and then the columns
            // update the count array with the corresponding values, then increment

           for (int row = 0; row < numbers.GetLength(0); row++)
            {
                for (int col = 0; col < numbers.GetLength(1); col++)
                {
                    count[numbers[row, col]]++;
                }
            }


            oneLabel.Text = count[1].ToString();
            twoLabel.Text = count[2].ToString();
            threeLabel.Text = count[3].ToString();
            fourLabel.Text = count[4].ToString();
            fiveLabel.Text = count[5].ToString();
            sixLabel.Text = count[6].ToString();
            sevenLabel.Text = count[7].ToString();
            eightLabel.Text = count[8].ToString();
            nineLabel.Text = count[9].ToString();
```

Comment: Does this help elucidate? `int theNumberAtRowCol = numbers[row, col]; count[theNumberAtRowCol] += 1;`

Comment: FYI you could also just do `foreach(var x in numbers) count[x]++;`

Comment: @JohnnyMopp, `count[theNumberAtRowCol] += 1;` makes sense to me. The other line is not as clear to me. I have always struggled with arrays. I understand that it is just looping through each number in the array and incrementing the counter based on which number it comes across. I just cannot seem to visualize it enough to feel confident in remembering how to do it.

Comment: @juharr This seems much more simple. This foreach would replace the nested for loop?

Comment: @Kayair Yes, multi-dimensional arrays will iterate through all the values when used in a foreach.  So that would work if you had a 3D or even 4D array instead.  Note that is not how a jagged arrray would work `int[][]` vs `int[,]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
count[numbers[row, col]]++;
```

First you need to know that numbers[row, col] is only accessing one number and it is taking that number and using it in the count array;

```
[0,0][1,0][2,0]
[0,1][1,1][2,1]
[0,2][1,2][2,2]
```

Each of the square braces represent only one number. You are taking that number and putting it into the count array and like count [0,0] but [0,0] is only an int like 1 or something.

Hope that is helpful I like to think of it like a tiktactoe board.